# Why am getting empty array in fetiching data using axios in react js and in urls?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I Created a view for article model and I have the data in my database but when I go on url then it's showing empty array
my below code
*view.py*

```
class ArticleView(RetrieveAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView, RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    pagination_class = ArticleSizeLimitPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.filter().order_by('-updated_on')
        def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Article.objects.get(id=self.request.data['id'], is_deleted=False)
        except Exception:
            return None

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
            instance.is_deleted = True
            instance.save()
            return Response(data='delete success')
        except Http404:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleView.as_view()),
    path('<uuid:pk>/', ArticleView.as_view()),
]
```

When I run the url then

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "sub_title": "",
    "upvote": null,
    "title": ""
}
```

Where did I do wrong? Is there issue in def function for RetrieveAPIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a view with selected mixins. You will be able to get one instance, update or delete. Is this what you want? Here you have the list of available mixins: [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes).

When you open the URL in the browser you probably get the DRF browsable API. It will show you nice forms to interact with your endpoints. If you want to get the article from the endpoint, you should provide URL with id (pk (where pk is primary key)).

Your URLs looks wrong. Please try:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(
    r"articles",
    ArticleView
)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"/", include(router.urls)),
]
```

I would recommend you to use [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead of building view from mixins. It should be easier.

```py
class ArticleView(ModelViewSet):
```

Please make it works with `ModelViewSet` (easier solution) and then try to narrow down with a harder solution, by defining mixins.